# Two different registration pages for laravel

Tags: laravel, registration

I'm trying to create two different registration pages for laravel - one will be for "students" and another for "mentors".

There are two ways in my head I could go about routing this:

1. Is to add in the localhost/register?user_type="mentor" and localhost/register?user_type="student". Then depending on the user_type parameter add a hidden input which will submit to laravel the user_type on registration.
2. To add a completely second registration page localhost/register_mentor or localhost/register_student

So, I used the makeauth scaffold. But here i'm confused.

1. I have no idea where the routes are for example:

In the "RegistrationController" I have

```
protected function create(array $data)
```

So I know I can edit this and add a user_type column in the database.

But I have no idea where this "create" is being called? So I don't know how to put in a a new registration page that will call this with the user_type.

2. Because I have no idea how it's being routed - I have no idea how I can copy the current register.blade.php and make a new one for a second registration page. It says in register.blade.php that the registration process is send to "{{ route('register') }" - but I have no idea where this is.

Hope I make sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the create method is called in the routes, like so :
Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')

It's part of the routes in Auth::routes created by the scaffold.

If you want to create your own RegisterController you can creates new folders like "Students" or "Mentor", or just "CustomAuth", in these folders you can create your own controllers which will be used to authenticate users. Then you call your controller and its methods in the routes just like the example i showed you !

Comment: if you choose to use more than one register controller to authenticate, make sure you name your routes diffrently, as for the path, so that the framework can differentiate the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create method is being called within the `register()` method found in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`.
You can override the `register()` method found by placing it in your RegisterController.

You also have access to the `$request` instance in the `register()` method so you can check for the url parameters.

In your `RegisterController.php` add the register method:

```
public function register(Request $request)
 {
     $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

     //Determine User type
     if($request->user_type === 'mentor'){
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));  
     }

     $this->guard()->login($user);

     return $this->registered($request, $user)
                     ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can manually create a second controller, a new model for this users and a new form for the new registration and make it manually, it will be easier.

But if you want to see what is done with Auth, you can go to vendor/laravel/framework/illuminate/auth and you've all the files used.